# как сделать адаптивное изображение затемненым на СSS или JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка, веб-программирование

с фиксированными значениями ширины и высоты у блока получилось сделать,а вот с адаптивным не выходит...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так?

```css
.img {
  position: relative;
}

img {
  display: block;
  border: none;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.img:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.57);
}
```

```html
<div class="img">
  <img src="http://301-1.ru/gen-mems/img_mems/4a4c2a53661ede617bd7437b4e728cbb.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: именно так,спасибо